# Java date custom format to ZonedDateTime

Tags: java, datetime

I am trying to parse following date format '2017-02-16T17:29:12.12T+0200' into a `ZonedDateTime`.

My goal  is to have `ZonedDateTime` that holds 2017-02-16T17:29:12.12 unmodified (not shifted to  a system time zone) and be associated with the time zone represented by +2 hours (from GMT).

```
@Test
public void testParseCustomDate() throws Exception {
    String format = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.S'T'Z";
    String value = "2017-02-16T17:29:12.12T+0300";

    Date date = new SimpleDateFormat(format).parse(value);
    System.out.println(date);

    ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(value, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format));
    System.out.println(dateTime);
}
```

In the example above the date is successfully parsed by the `SimpleDateFormat` but not with `ZonedDateTime.parse`

Answer (score 1):

[SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) are different. To parse your sample date, you should add one "S" for second fraction:

```
String format = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SS'T'Z";
```

It will produce following output:

```
Thu Feb 16 15:29:12 CET 2017
2017-02-16T17:29:12.120+03:00
```